# MySQL Workbench sends computer name with login not IP

Tags: remote-access, mysql5, credentials

I am attempting to connect MySQLWorkbench to a remote MySQL Server.

The server has granted access to

```
user@IPAddress
```

However, when I try to connect MySQLWorkbench, it sends

```
user@computername
```

instead.  How do I configure the connection to use the IP address instead in MySQLWorkbench?

Reference:  The remote server is on the local network, so I need to use the local IP address assigned to my client.

**EDIT**

What I have tried so far:

executed

```
sudo service mysql start --skip-name-resolve
```

from the server:

```
mysql -u user@IPAddress -p --host=(ServerIPAddress)
```

Returns:

```
mysql>
```

So that tells me the user account is operational.  Furthermore, I confirmed it exists using:

```
select user from mysql.user;
```

returning a table of all users, of which the user I am using is present.

I have also opened the port 3306:

```
sbin/iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -s clientIPAddress -p tcp --destination-port3306 -j ACCEPT
```

Still I encounter

```
Access Denied for user
user@ComputerName (using password: YES)
```

**Answer**:
I deleted the original user account

```
DROP USER 'user@IPAdress'
```

and added it back:

```
GRANT ALL on foo.* To 'user'@'IPAdress' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

The tick locations are significant as the user name was actually:

```
user@IPAdress
```

not

```
user
```

MySQLWorkbench is now able to connect!

Answer (score 4):

MySQL automatically attempts to do a reverse DNS lookup of any IP's that try to connect to it, and the DNS name is what gets checked against your grants.

If you start up `mysqld` with the `--skip-name-resolve` option, it will skip DNS lookups and match against IP addresses instead.

Reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/host-cache.html

Comment: I restarted MySQL Server with the switch you suggested and it still is not letting me connect and echoing `Access denied for user@computername`

Comment: What happens if you try to connect with `mysql -u (whatever) -p --host=(ip address of the server)` ?

Comment: I can do this from the server and connect just fine using the credentials I am using with MySQLWorkbench.  However, MySQL is not installed on my client so I can't do it from there.